# How do you differentiate a time machine from a disintegration chamber?

Tags: science-fiction, time-travel, logistics

In settings where time travel is possible but only backwards in time (Terminator), how did the scientists that developed the machine know that the subjects sent back in time actually were time traveling instead of just being destroyed outright? From the perspective of the people in "the present" (the origin point for the time travelers) the subject enters the machine and after it's turned on they vanish.

My question is how would you know for certain the intended time travelers made it to past (let alone the intended destination), instead of simply being atomized?

I am trying to write a story where prisoners in the future are sent back in time as a form of exile for their crimes, but I got stuck when I realized that without some way of confirming the prisoners are actually being sent backwards in time this would seem to the people of that future as nothing more than an overly elaborate and expensive method of execution.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you atomize something, how is there nothing left? Surely there are...well... atoms.

Comment: This seems highly dependent upon how time travel works, both mechanically and how the laws of your world allow for time travel. Without knowing that we're left to fill in details of your world ourselves before we're even capable of answering this question. Furthermore questions that are asking for help brainstorming or generating ideas, are not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Have the engineers test it on themselves. Also test them on suicidal behavior beforehand.

Answer (score 13):

**Short trips.**

TC is going to test my time machine.  I am going to send brave TC back in time.  Back in time 3 minutes.  I tell TC to bring something awesome from the future.

We are going to do the test in 3 minutes because my favorite show finishes then; TC likes it too and we are watching together.  TC from 3 minutes in the future arrives.  TC high fives the TC that is watching my show with me.  TC from the future tells us how the show ends because that is how TC is.  As payback TC from the future gets flicked on the head by TC of the present and a minor altercation ensues but they are evenly matched.

It is time to use the time machine.  TC of the present grabs my box of Cheezits and hops in before I can get it back.  Hops in the time machine, not the box of cheezits.

Now there is 1 TC with me who is the one who gave away the ending of the show.  TC forgot about the cheezits in TCs jacket which got crushed during the minor altercation.  I guess that is the something awesome from the future.

We know the time machine is safe.  No-one got disintegrated.  The cheezit crumbs taste ok.   TC was still very much TC.  We could do a few more jumps and in fact we must have decided to do that because TC from 30 minutes in the future has just showed up.  TC from the future has a new box of Cheezits which are the extra toasty kind and it is family size so enough for all 3 of us.  All 4 because another TC just showed up and now things are going to get tricky.

Answer (score 8):

### Isotopic analysis

If the volume in the time machine swaps with the target volume in the past, then you can do isotopic analysis on the air or whatever else has come through to the present after pressing the button. Nuclear wars or the absence of them will show up.

Edit: You could possibly even send back some slow decaying chemical tracer, or dust sized microprocessor with a realtime clock, and sample the air from the same spot over a time period; there's lots of possible riffs on this.

Comment: I like this answer since it's the only one posted so far that works in branching-timeline forms of time travel (i.e. if the time traveler changes the past, it makes a new future that the scientists left behind can't access). However, if the machine really swapped matter between points in time, it could also pull stuff from the past into the future, which the OP stated explicitly wasn't allowed. Or maybe it is allowed, since it doesn't move anything further into the future than the time machine itself? I dunno, the post is really vague.

Comment: Maybe the mass going backwards to forwards ratio has to be thousands to one, effectively (but not completely) preventing pulling pretty much anything forwards?

Answer (score 6):

## History records

I know that in this day and age this is a contemptious issue, but if something is in history books, it probably happened.

So just check if your prisoner is ever mentioned anywhere. To make it even more likely they make it to the records, [send them dressed as clowns. Historians love that, so it will have a lasting impact that you can read about ages later.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_clown_sightings)

Comment: Upvote for "contemptious issue"!

Answer (score 5):

## The Many-Colored Land:

Julian May had a similar issue, and sent his time travelers back with items made to be able to survive in the fossil record. I don't remember the exact things he used, but carved stones, synthetic diamonds, or gold with specific elemental contaminants all come to mind. Then, the people in the modern world need to look through museums and sites near the supposed destination for proof that the artifacts survived to the modern age.

Obviously, if there is a deliberate effort to prevent a signal from going forward (like by the aliens on Earth in May's book) then this would be foiled.

Comment: May didn't actually have this issue. Things COULD go forward in time, but they would age the entire time. People would die, but you could get a message through if you etched it in stone.

Answer (score 5):

Does your machine work?  Stay out of the room.  Have your associate go remove anything in the machine and leave, saying nothing about what he finds.  You go in and use the machine to send something back 10 minutes.  Now you go talk to your associate and see if they removed said object from the machine.

If they got the object you have a time machine, if they didn't you either don't understand your machine or it's not a time machine at all.  No paradoxes in either case.

Comment: I'm not following this answer, do you mean remove a part of the machine??  Can you clarify what you mean please.

Comment: @deep64blue No--you put something in the machine and send it back.  The test is whether it arrives.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the time machine would need to be a tested, proven thing before it can be used in executions. How you test it however depends on the kind of time-travel you imagine.

If you take the "fixed destiny, no paradoxes" route then testing is simple - send something back in time for a short duration. Let's say 5 minutes. See if it arrived before it was sent.

If time travel creates parallel timelines then it's harder, but you can still get somewhere - have the scientists send back in time information about their time machine and the construction. Keep hammering away at the theory, fix the theoretical mistakes you've uncovered, keep sending back. You'll never see the results, but your counterpart in a parallel reality will. Probably in a lot of parallel realities. And they can  keep doing that until one of those timelines has plenty of proof from other timelines.

Yet another option opens if you change the design of your time machine. Instead of disappearing, open a portal which you can walk through both ways. The portal creates an alternate timeline, but while it's open, both realities are linked. When it closes though, it's bye bye forever.

Last but not least, you can also just handwave it away if it's not relevant to your story.